# Trigger tab event on matching input length

Tags: javascript, input, vuejs2, vue-component, dom-events

I've a certain requirement where I need to trigger a tab event after matching that criteria. So, whenever the value of the input length matches given length I need to trigger tab event, so that I can move the focus to next focusable element.

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="username" @input="handleInput">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      username: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput(e) {
      const value = e.target.value;
      if (value && value.length >= 5) {
        // I would like to trigger tab event here
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this can be done using Vue ref and javascript, Let's say you have another input element, we can use Vue ref to access the dom element itself,

```
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model="username" @input="handleInput">
    <input type="text" ref="input2" />
</div>
```

In the js side, you can use the `focus` method of the element,

```
if (value && value.length >= 5) {
  this.$refs["input2"].focus();
}
```

Comment: Yeah that is possible only when the two elements belongs to same component, but I've inputs belongs to two separate components

Comment: Do you have a fixed element to be focused when it reaches 5 characters or will that change dynamically?

Comment: Yeah, the second element changes dynamically

Comment: You can emit a custom event inside the if condition and you can set the focus using it's event handler

Comment: I don't get you